# mysql: Replacing column value with values from column from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two datasets, A and B. In both datasets, I have a column called "Campaign" but they were named differently. For example, in A, campaign is referred to as 'CDE-332 Blabla' and in B, the same campaign is referred to as 'FGI-332 Bleh Bleh'. Another campaign might be 'CDE-345 Blabla' in A and 'FGI-345 Bleh Bleh' in B. Basically, it is the 3 digits in each dataset that connect the rows.

My question becomes: Is there a way with mysql to replace in A the campaigns seen in B, that have the matching 3 digits? Thanks!

Comment: Are the 3 digits always at the same place in the column value?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not.

Comment: OK, I've changed my answer to use `LOCATE` to find the `-` before the 3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables using `SUBSTR()` as the join condition, and then update Table A.

```
UPDATE TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b 
ON SUBSTR(a.campaign, LOCATE(a.campaign, '-')+1, 3) = SUBSTR(b.campaign, LOCATE(b.campaign, '-')+1, 3)
SET a.campaign = b.campaign
```